# How to horizontally align elements of lists

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I would like the elements of a tuple of two lists to have the same horizontal alignment. I have tried the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  C_0 = \left(
  \begin{aligned}
    (&f_1, &f_2, &f_3, &f_4), \\
    (&0, &0, &1, &0)
  \end{aligned}
  \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image]

I have tried replacing the `aligned` environment with a `matrix` environment, but this results in too much spacing between elements of the list:

[image]

Comment: This is more like a pmatrix or array.  Aligned alternates right aligned and left aligned fields.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo, that explains the weird alignment. Maybe matrix or array are the best options.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it something like this you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
  C_0 = \begin{pmatrix}
    ( f_1, &f_2, &f_3, &f_4 ), \\
    ( 0, &0, &1, &0 )
  \end{pmatrix} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]